# PostgreSQL среднее в строке

Tags: postgresql, sql

Может, вопрос и простой, но гугл отчаянно пытается меня отправить находить среднее по столбцу, а мне надо по строке.

```
     SELECT 
            "FH_09_Q" ,                             
            "FH_10_Q" ,                             
            "FH_11_Q" ,
          ("FH_09_Q" + "FH_10_Q" + "FH_11_Q"),
            ("FH_09_Q" + "FH_10_Q"+ "FH_11_Q")/3        
            FROM 
            "SC_Wonder"."TMining_New" 
            where "FMineObj_ID" = 16
            and "FDate" ='2015-01-26'
```

### В общем, есть строка с данными. Как найти сумму и среднее при условии, что есть пустые поля?

UPD

```
     SELECT 
        "FH_09_Q" ,                             
        "FH_10_Q" ,                             
        "FH_11_Q" ,
    (COALESCE("FH_09_Q",0) + COALESCE("FH_10_Q",0) + COALESCE("FH_11_Q",0)) as sum,
        (COALESCE("FH_09_Q",0) + COALESCE("FH_10_Q",0) + COALESCE("FH_11_Q",0))/3 as avg
   
        FROM 
        "SC_Wonder"."TMining_New" 
        where "FMineObj_ID" = 16
        and "FDate" ='2015-01-26'
```

[image]

но при таком случае как узнать число непустых полей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо вам нужен [COALESCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html#AEN12663).

```
(COALESCE(FH_09_Q,0) + COALESCE(FH_10_Q,0) + COALESCE(FH_11_Q,0))/3
```

Comment: А ну точно. Так я выгребу непустые поля? А вот как узнать число непустых полей

Comment: @anunak, не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду. Сравнить с null можно через is null. Узнать количество - посчитать... 1.. 2.. 3..

Answer (score -3):

есть встроеные функции sum и avg. [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-aggregate.html)

Comment: << гугл отчаянно пытается меня отправить находить среднее по столбцу а мне надо по строке. >>
sum и avg для столбцов а у меня строка